# Add a class with Jquery or Javascript to <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have the following markup:

```
<ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="home.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php" title="Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need help figuring out how to add a class using Jquery or Javascript (preferably Jquery) according to the active page. Example, when on the "Home.php" page, I would like to add the class ".selected" to the active `<a>` tag and at the same time add the class ".none" to all the other links.

Therefore, when being on the "home.php" page the code should look like this:

```
<ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="home.php" class="selected" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php" class="none" title="Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php" class="none" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" class="none" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

According to the way the rest of the code works, I need the class to be assigned to the `<a>` tag and not to the entire `<li>` item. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this (you might need to use different properties from `location`, like `href` or `pathname`, but you get the idea):

```
$('ul.menubar a').each(function(){
    if(location.href === this.href){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('ul.menubar a').not(this).addClass('none');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or better yet:

```
$('ul.menubar a').addClass('none').filter('a[href="'+location.pathname+'"]')
    .removeClass('none').addClass('selected');
```

Here's more info on the `location` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: First one worked like a charm. 2nd one, only assigned the class "none", and not the "selected" one, even when using "location.href", but thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @antigaprime: You're welcome.  I wasn't too sure about the 2nd one, I just threw it up there for the heck of it. :-P

Answer (score 0):

A very simple method, no guarantees on efficiency though.
HTML :

```
<ul class="menubar">
    <li><a href="home.php" class="selected" id="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php" class="none" id="Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php" class="none" id="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" class="none" id="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#"+ $.trim( $("title").html() ) ).addClass("selected");
});
```

Edit: added $.trim(), just an extra step.

Comment: you probably want .text() not .html() methinks

Comment: You can also do `document.title`, not sure if it's any faster though :-P

Comment: document.title is inbuilt javascript feature. Hence, that'll be faster than using Jquery, any day!

Answer (score 0):

Just add ID attribute to your "a tags" and using jQuery do:

```
$("#home").addClass('selected');
```